# Why do the indicators above doors stay gray in Portal 2?

Tags: portal-2

I am playing Portal 2 CO-OP and have finished chapters 1 and 2. Above the doors (and in the pre-chamber) there are indicators. I think orange indicates if the chapter chamber number has been solved, but what does blue indicate? Something with the other player? Why does it stay gray? How to make it blue?

Or is it just something meaningless - because blue/orange is a theme across Portal series?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Based on [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Portal/comments/h1u3u/anyone_know_why_some_blueorange_blocks_dont_light/) reddit thread, the bars indicate which chambers have been completed by the respective player. As each chambers are completed, the bars will be filled in.

- The **blue** bars indicate which chambers have been completed by the player controlling **Atlas**
- The **orange** bars indicate which chambers have been completed by the player controlling **P-Body**

In the first image, the player controlling Atlas still needs to complete Chambers 5 and 6 in the Team Building course.

In the second image, the player controlling Atlas still needs to complete Chamber 1 in the Mass and Velocity course.

Comment: Based on this information, I assume OP is P-Body, since they've completed all courses.

Comment: Yeah this is basically it, blue stands for the player playing Atlas, so OP's friend, or the game's host, and orange stands for OP himself. The tick mark is also grayed out on the blue side since Atlas hasn't finished the entire course yet, as in his bar has gray in both pictures.

Comment: Is it known why chapters 1 and 2 are not completely blue and orange? We both played the chambers and solved them together.

Comment: @Gizmo It's been a very long time since I've played Portal 2, so it's difficult to say, but is it possible there was perhaps a missed objective or something similar in the chamber?